# rails 5 NoMethodError in RegistrationsController#new undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Working on a course project and using rails 5 however the course isn't using rails 5 receiving this error after implementing this in NoMethodError in RegistrationsController#new
undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass

## was this before: class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

```
  class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :configure_permitted_paramters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
    def configure_permitted_paramters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) << :fullname
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) << :fullname << :cell_number << :license_plate_number << :vehicle_description << :email << :password
       end
   end
```

My routes changed to this as well part of the problem?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#home'

  devise_for :users, 
    path => '', 
    :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile'},
controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks',
    :registrations => 'registrations'
                                                        }

  resources :users, only: [:show]

end
```

Comment: NoMethodError in RegistrationsController#new would be the code in app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

Comment: Yes the top code portion is from the reg controller,

Answer (score 0):

Your registration controller is redefining the Application Controller rather than defining the registration controller.  Try the following:

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
end
```

Comment: I would simply replace it for example:                              class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController.       def end                                                             Protect_from_forgery with: :exception    before_action :configure_permitted_paramters, if: :devise_controller?    protected     def configure_permitted_paramters         devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) << :fullname         devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) << :fullname << :cell_number << :license_plate_number << :vehicle_description << :email << :password     end end

Comment: I can't read that.  Please edit your question with the code above.

Comment: I changed it as illustrated above. Not surprising had a diff error as I'm such a newby it hurts and not sure how to input/ integrate your suggestion Andy. Thank you for your help